# Ideas how to store code snippets/objects (not json) in mongodb?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

So let's say I am doing converting csv to json in node.js, and doing mapping between the fields found in the customer's input file and the object that my platform requires, such as:

```
 var objInvoice = {
        "id" : guid.create().value, 
        "financingType" : "scf", 
        "batchId" : batchId, 
        "recordTypeCode" : inv.kayittipi, 
        "buyerReference" : result[0].tedarikcireferans, 
        "supplierReference" : inv.tedarikcireferans, 
        "invoiceDate" : moment(inv.faturatarih +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "certifiedInvoiceAmount" : inv.odenecekfaturatutar, 
        "currencyCode" : inv.parabirimi, 
        "maturityDate" : moment(inv.orjvadetarihi +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "correctedMaturityDate" : moment(inv.orjvadetarihi +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "originalInvoiceAmount" : inv.orjfaturatutar, 
        "invoiceNo" : inv.faturano, 
        "invoiceSerialNo" : inv.faturaserino, 
        "noterizedDocNo" : inv.belgenoteryevmiyeno, 
        "hashCode" : inv.hashCode, 
        "forecastDate" : inv.fiilivadetarihi, 
        "supplierTaxId" : inv.tedarikcivkn, 
        "supplierName" : inv.tedarikciadi, 
        "invoiceType" : inv.faturatipi, 
        "buyerAccountNumber" : inv.aliciiban, 
        "buyerTaxId" : inv.alicivkn, 
        "fiReference" : inv. bankakodu, 
        "bankBranchCode" : inv.bankasubeno, 
        "invoiceUploadStatus" : inv.dosyakayitstatu, 
        "gwCode" : "111110000000", 
        "gwCodeExplanation" : "", 
        "invoiceDiscountDate" : null, 
        "additionalInformation1" : inv.aciklama1, 
        "additionalInformation2" : inv.aciklama2,
        "additionalInformation3" : inv.aciklama3,
        "lastModificationDate" : null, 
        "newInvoiceId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "oldInvoiceId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "supplierIban" : "", 
        "supplierBankName" : "", 
        "customUniqueId" : "", 
        "deductionReason" : "", 
        "paymentObligationNo" : null, 
        "deductionAmount" : "", 
        "sellAmount" : "", 
        "invoiceAmountWithoutVat" : "",
        "uploadDate" : now.toISOString(), 

    }
```

but a customer2 may have a different positioned fields,or even different headers in file - such as:

```
var objInvoice = {
        "id" : guid.create().value, 
        "financingType" : "scf", 
        "batchId" : batchId, 
        "recordTypeCode" : inv.element1, 
        "buyerReference" : result[0].element2, 
        "supplierReference" : inv.element2, 
        "invoiceDate" : moment(inv.element3 +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "certifiedInvoiceAmount" : inv.element4, 
        "currencyCode" : inv.element5, 
        "maturityDate" : moment(inv.element6 +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "correctedMaturityDate" : moment(inv.element6 +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString(), 
        "originalInvoiceAmount" : inv.element7, 
        "invoiceNo" : inv.element8, 
        "invoiceSerialNo" : inv.element9, 
        "noterizedDocNo" : inv.element10, 
        "hashCode" : inv.element11, 
        "forecastDate" : inv.element12, 
        "supplierTaxId" : inv.element13, 
        "supplierName" : inv.element14, 
        "invoiceType" : inv.element15, 
        "buyerAccountNumber" : inv.element16, 
        "buyerTaxId" : inv.element17, 
        "fiReference" : inv. element18, 
        "bankBranchCode" : inv.element19, 
        "invoiceUploadStatus" : inv.element20, 
        "gwCode" : "111110000000", 
        "gwCodeExplanation" : "", 
        "invoiceDiscountDate" : null, 
        "additionalInformation1" : inv.element21, 
        "additionalInformation2" : inv.element22,
        "additionalInformation3" : inv.element23,
        "lastModificationDate" : null, 
        "newInvoiceId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "oldInvoiceId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "supplierIban" : "", 
        "supplierBankName" : "", 
        "customUniqueId" : "", 
        "deductionReason" : "", 
        "paymentObligationNo" : null, 
        "deductionAmount" : "", 
        "sellAmount" : "", 
        "invoiceAmountWithoutVat" : "",
        "uploadDate" : now.toISOString(), 

     }
```

so I was thinking if it's possible to store each 'mapping' per customer in mongodb? and pulls the correct objInvoice via customer reference?

The issue is, objInvoice cannot be stored as a json document since it contains variables such as inv.element1.

I've also tried to store as a one big string  (I tried with {} and without {} ), I was able to store it fine but when I pulled it from the code and unstringnified it the vars didn't get processed as expected.

Any ideas fellow good programmers?

Or the only way is to store those in seperate js files per customer?

Comment: Did you (de)stringify with JSON.stringify and JSON.parse? Also, does the different order matter and needs to be saved?

Comment: I have tried JSON.parse, but the object is not a valid json object after all, since it contains variables  ( json values need to be either string or number or boolean)  - i did try to store them as string but the vars didn't get processed in code after i turned it back to object.   How does the order affect the logic?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not even a valid Javascript object... you should restructure your data in order to be valid Javascript object and/or JSON

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your data is not even valid Javascript Objects or JSON.

An idea is to convert values, like `moment(inv.orjvadetarihi +"-140000"  , "YYMMDD-HHmmss").toISOString()` which are not valid, into strings (escaping correctly). As a result you will be able to `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. The strings can then be `eval`uated in your code.

Preprocessing your data to escape non-string values into strings certainly works. You may use regexes.

Comment: That entirely depends on your code. If it doesn't in its simplest form, some more complex eval logic depending on some parsing will. If push comes to shove, you will have to parse.

Comment: eval worked like a charm, all i had to do was fetching (dbobjInvoice) from mongo then var objInvoice =  eval(dbobjInvoice)  ....where dbobjInvoice is a big string stored in mongodb

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped